# Problems with java graphics

Tags: java

Can anyone give me some information what did I do wrong? Program runs but drowing a rectangle or anything else doesnt work.  There is just empty space on the middle. I tried open the program from terminal and eclipse on kubuntu 15 and windows. Always with the same result.

I m just starting my adventure with java so please be patient.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyGUI {
JFrame frame;
JLabel label;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MyGUI gui = new MyGUI();
    gui.go();
}

public void go()
{
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JButton labelButton = new JButton("Change label");
    labelButton.addActionListener(new LabelListener());

    JButton colorButton = new JButton("Change color");
    colorButton.addActionListener(new ColorListener());

    label = new JLabel("LABEL");
    DrawSmth2 drawPanel = new DrawSmth2();

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, colorButton);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, labelButton);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, label);

    frame.setSize(680,480);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

class LabelListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        label.setText("DONE");
    }
}

class ColorListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        frame.repaint();        
    }
}
public class DrawSmth2 extends JPanel{

    public void PaintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't change your question in a way it will invalidate already posted answers. If you have followup question ask it in new post.

Comment: Take 2 or 3 months and study the [Oracle Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Answer (score 1):

Java is case-sensitive which means that `PaintComponent` is not the same as `paintComponent`. To avoid such problems always add `@Override` annotation to methods you want to override (if you are not overriding existing method compiler will inform you about it - more info: [When do you use Java's @Override annotation and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why)).

Also don't forget to call `super.paintComponent(g);` at start of your own implementation of `paintComponent` to let Swing perform standard operations needed to properly paint this component.

Comment: Ohh... So silly mistake. Thanks, but now after clicking the colorButton color of area on the middle is not changing.

Comment: @pwl.salach And which part of your code you believe should change color?

Comment: I copied the easiest version of paintComponent. It should draw a ovall with gradient of 2 random colors. But it s always black.

Comment: That is subject for separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Just add gloabal variable count;

```html
int count=0;
class ColorListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  count++;
        frame.repaint();        
    }
}
public class DrawSmth2 extends JPanel{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
 if(count%2==1) 
    g.setColor(Color.blue);

    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
 
    }
}
```